# The exact, formal definition of a prabolic problem/equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, definition, nonlinear-system, parabolic-pde

While searching for information about properties of parabolic problems, I stumbled upon a publication titled "Study of Nonlinear Parabolic Problems".

This made me wonder why the writers specifically mentioned the word "nonlinear" since I believed that parabolic problems were inherently nonlinear. This led me to question the exact definition of a parabolic problem or equation.

Is it possible to have a linear parabolic problem?
If so, what is the definition of a linear parabolic equation?

Comment: PDE is linear when we can use Principle of Superposition , else it is nonlinear. [[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle ]] PDE is Parabolic when Discriminant is 0 [[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_partial_differential_equation ]]  We can have linear Parabolic / nonlinear Parabolic / linear Elliptic / nonlinear Elliptic / ETC.

Comment: The heat equation is the prime example of a parabolic PDE and is as linear as it can possibly be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "Handbook of Differential Equations" 3rd edition Daniel Zwillinger.

"6. Classification of Partial Differential Equations"

Page 37 :
[image: Page 37]

Page 38 :
[image: 38]

(Point 1) In general , $A,B,C$ may or may not be Constants.
When these are Constants , then Discriminant $D$ is also Constant.
Discriminant $D$ having Zero value indicates Parabolic PDE.

Eg :
$(A,B,C)=(0.1,2,10)$ : $D=0$
$(A,B,C)=(x^2,2xy,y^2)$ : $D=0$

(Point 2) When $u$ is a Solution & $v$ is a Solution , we could try $u+v$ , which will also be a Solution when $\Psi$ is linear.
Otherwise , we can not add the Solutions , due to nonlinear $\Psi$

Hence we can have Parabolic linear PDE & Parabolic nonlinear PDE & $n^{th}$ Degree PDE& $k^{th}$ Order PDE & ETC.
Classification is almost unlimited.